# How to Loop with Categoy on jS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have array like this

```
let students = [
            [{name: 'didi', class: 'one'}, {name: 'dudu', class: 'one'}],
            [{name: 'dede', class: 'two'}]
        ];
```

I want the result like this...
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz5TS.png)

I have tried to make loop with this below code...

```
let studentsCatg='';

        for (let i=0; i<students.length; i++){

            for (let j=0; j<students[i].length; j++){
                studentsCatg += '<ul style=\"border: 1px solid #ddd\">'
                    +'<li><p>'+students[i][j].name+'</p>'+students[i][j].class+'</p></li>'
                    +'</ul>'                
            }   

        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = studentsCatg;
```

But the result like this..

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acEXf.png)

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: The first image is not very clear... To me both the result and expected result look the same. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: The difference is that ul defines a class. So he made a mistake by creating a <ul> within the second loop.

Comment: didi dede dudu what a combination of words !!

Comment: @mosia is right.  The UL tags just need to be outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little changes in your code:

```
let studentsCatg = '';
for (let i=0; i<students.length; i++){
    studentsCatg += '<ul style=\"border: 1px solid #ddd\">';
    for (let j=0; j<students[i].length; j++){
        studentsCatg += '<li><p>'+students[i][j].name+'</p>'+students[i][j].class+'</p></li>';                
    }   
    studentsCatg += '</ul>';
}
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = studentsCatg;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function()
{
  let studentLists = [
    [{name: 'didi', class: 'one'}, {name: 'dudu', class: 'one'}],
    [{name: 'dede', class: 'two'}]
  ];

  let container = document.getElementById("result");

  studentLists.map(function(studentList)
  {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
      ul.classList.add("class");
    
    studentList.map(function(object)
    {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = object.name + " <br />" + object.class;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    
    container.appendChild(ul);
  });


})();
```

```css
.class{
  border: thin solid #dbdbdb;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of categorizing them by thier `class`

```js
let students = [
  [{name: 'didi', class: 'one'}, {name: 'dudu', class: 'one'}],
  [{name: 'dede', class: 'two'}]
];
        
let tempObj = {};

students.forEach( stArr=>{
  stArr.forEach( st=> 
    tempObj[st.class]?
    tempObj[st.class].push(st):
    tempObj[st.class] = [st]
  )
})

console.log(tempObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to change your implementation. You needed to create your `<ul>` outside the inner `for` loop so that the list of students within a class can be created as `<li>` inside of the `<ul>` you created. So you previous code was creating `<ul>` for every student.

```js
let students = [
    [{name: 'didi', class: 'one'}, {name: 'dudu', class: 'one'}],
    [{name: 'dede', class: 'two'}]
];

let studentsCatg='';

for (let i=0; i<students.length; i++)
{
  //Here I placed studentsCatg outside of the second loop.
  studentsCatg += '<ul style=\"border: 1px solid #ddd\">';
  
  for (let j=0; j<students[i].length; j++)
  {
     // For each student, add <li> inside the <ul> created above
     studentsCatg += '<li><p>'+students[i][j].name+'</p>'+students[i][j].class+'</p></li>';          
  }  
  
  //  Close the <ul> created for the class i
  studentsCatg += '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = studentsCatg;
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can first change the variable name 'students' because it is very generic. Don't quitely understand why it was made that way the array (maybe this problem can be fixed before in a simpler way).

But lets keep it and make it this way:

```
let students = [[{name: 'didi', class: 'one'}, {name: 'dudu', class: 'one'}],[{name: 'dede', class: 'two'}]];

var classRoom = {}; // object containing classroom name as key and students as array
for (let i=0; i<students.length; i++){
    let mixedStudents = students[i]; // get all students from current position

    mixedStudents.forEach(student => {
        let studentClassRoom = classRoom[student.class];
        if (!studentClassRoom) {
          classRoom[student.class] = [];
        }

        classRoom[student.class].push(student.name);
    });

}

console.log(classRoom);
```

Hope this helps, probably you can replace the first for loop in a more fancy forEach loop too.